# Issue with payment for using API Key (Maps JavaScript API) on my Website

Tags: google-cloud-platform, website, javascript

English translation:
Subject: Issue with payment for using API Key (Maps JavaScript API) on my Website

Content:

I am currently having an issue with the payment for using the API Key (Maps JavaScript API) on my Website.

I currently have a $350 free credit.

I can select the project in the Budgets & Alerts section, but I do not see the Maps JavaScript API service.

Please kindly guide me on how to use it.

Comment: I am not 100% sure. The Maps JavaScript API is the name of the SDK. The Billing SKU is the Maps API.